# How maked beautiful tables from table object in R

Tags: r, dataframe, gt

I want to make a beautiful table from table in R. This is the table created from factor variables:

`a=factor(sample(1:4, 10000, replace=TRUE))`

`b=factor(sample(c(0,1,NA), 10000, replace=TRUE))`

`table(a,b,exclude=NULL)`

This is the output from table command:

```
  b
a     0   1 <NA>
  1 855 824  851
  2 802 843  870
  3 821 868  855
  4 795 786  830
```

I want to know how can I add tittle to this table and format to make a beautiful table like using gt or another similar package

Comment: what do you mean? Do you want to create a table in latex, or html, or... please be more specific. This question is too broad.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it. I want to create a table in HTML adding title and format to make it look great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c <- table(a,b,exclude=NULL)

library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(gt)

c %>%
  tibble::as_tibble() %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = b, values_from = n) %>%
  gt::gt() %>%
  gt::tab_header(
    title = "How do A and B coincide?",
    subtitle = "Such a great table"
  ) %>% gt::tab_spanner(
    label = "b",
    columns = 2:4
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, c is your table object. When converted to a tibble it comes in in a longer format, where the b value is defined in a column called `b` and the count is in another column called `n`. The pivot_wider step converts that to a wide table like your original `table` object.

Comment: I tried to run it but I get this error: `Error in as.data.frame.default(value, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame`.

Comment: Please ignore my last comment. I forgot to include a code line from your answer. Thanks for your help